# Как на форме изобразить треугольник по координатам?

Tags: c#, winforms, графика

Сделал кое как что смог, если вписываю положительные координаты - вроде норм отображает, пишу отрицательные - треугольник пропадает. Внизу скину код метода, помогите пофиксить!

```
private void PaintTriangle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3)
{
    Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
    PointF point1 = new PointF((float)x1 * 10, (float)y1 * 10);
    PointF point2 = new PointF((float)x2 * 10, (float)y2 * 10);
    PointF point3 = new PointF((float)x3 * 10, (float)y3 * 10);

    PointF[] curvePoints =
    {
     point1,
     point2,
     point3
     };
    g.DrawPolygon(p, curvePoints);
}
```

Comment: Он просто рисуется за пределами экрана

Comment: Вам нужно преобразовать координаты так, чтобы минимальная точка по оси x имела координату хотя бы 0, аналогично с осью y.

Comment: как это исправить в коде, не подскажите?